# What is the relationship between LUIS apps and Botframework composer?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

When I create a new question asking for free text in the bot framework composer, a new intent name is created, which is fine. However, when I then look on the LUIS portal, it seems to create a whole new App (new App name etc). for it.  If there is a new app name every time, how can I access different intents?  Very frustrating and clunky solution at the moment it seems...

Comment: It can be a bit confusing. Perhaps this docs page on using [LUIS in Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-luis?tabs=v2x) may help.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to publish your bot using same profile every time.**

[image: The publishing profile look like this]

***Just make sure you are using the same publishing profile whenever you publish your bot to azure.***

[image: Choose the publish target and select the bot than publish.]

And the new app created on LUIS portal makes training look more easy. Every intent represents different set of entities.